# On sshd server how can I see what connection what cipher is using?

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd

I'm administrating a ssh server, serving multiple users. Some asked to be available to use a cipher "arcfour", so I enabled it.

But I am now trying to actually see which connection and user is using it. Is there a way to list the connections with the information about the cipher used in each connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `LogLevel DEBUG` in the server `sshd_config`. Then you should see messages as

```
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
```

Saying what Cipher, MAC and compression is used during the connection.

Comment: Where did you take this output from? I'm looking at: 
"# journalctl -u sshd |tail -10" but get no such rows..

Comment: And restart the sshd server of course after the change of the configuration file.

Comment: Running `journalctl -u sshd | grep "server->client"` gives me these lines. It is probably not in the `tail`.

Comment: Yes, that's it. But sadly it doesn't tell which cipher for which connection is being used..

Comment: You would see that in the context of other logs saying from where the user came (`Connection from 192.168.122.1 port 49858 on 192.168.122.41 port 22` and `Accepted publickey for root from 192.168.122.1 port 49858 ssh2: RSA SHA256:jLoy5uXEhlClW/u5mC8WRQ7a/AebWz93A+EeZMVnuMg` for example).

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks!